# Why is second iterator over array 'arr' not working in Hackerrank compiler?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to run simple code for finding second highest number in array 'arr' but second array iterator over 'arr' is not working.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = map(int, input().split())

    a1=-101
    a2=-102
    for i in arr:
        if a1<i :a1=i

    for j in arr: 
        print(j)
```

I expect arr value to be printed but getting ~ no response on stdout ~

Comment: Iterator like map can only be iterated once.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Python 3, `map` is an iterator (it doesn't give a list). To be able to iterate over it more than once, wrap it in a call to `list()`:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Comment: Better: `[int(i) for i in input().split()]` and please dont call it `arr` since it is not an array.

Comment: @KlausD. It is a matter of style, not objective good/bad.

Answer (score 0):

`arr = map(int, input().split())` producinng a generator and iterating over a generator, without make it iterable first, that is why you are getting error.

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Comment: There is no error here. The point is second iteration does not work because the iterator is exhausted.

Comment: i think we need to C where to give python Rat to exit from exhausted state.